# getting black screenshots with Robotium in openGL project

Tags: android, opengl-es, robotium

I have an Android project that uses OpenGL with C++ and NDK, and it uses a game engine that uses GLSurfaceView. I want to test my project with Robotium, and I am using its version 4.1.

When I try to do an screenshot in my tests with:

```
solo.takeScreenshot();
```

I'm getting a black screenshot, and I can see this error on LogCat:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mRenderer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:631)
    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Reflect$FieldRf.getField(Reflect.java:110)
    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Reflect$FieldRf.out(Reflect.java:68)
    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.wrapAllGLViews(Solo.java:2301)
    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.takeScreenshot(Solo.java:2285)
    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.takeScreenshot(Solo.java:2271)
[...]
```

Any advice?